# How to get the average of consecutive occurrences when meet certain condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data` that has payment schedule for customers that is ordered by transaction date.I want to calculate the average number of consecutive failed payments and average number of consecutive success payments.The table looks like below:

```
customer_id |transaction_id.|failed_or_success  | transaction_date 
  1         |1              |success            |2021-01-01
  1         |2              |success            |2021-01-15
  1         |3              |failed             |2021-01-30
  1         |4              |success            |2021-02-15
```

For example, the average number of consecutive success payment would be `(2+1)/2=1.5`, the first `2` comes from transaction_id 1 & 2.the second `1` comes from transaction_id 4. And the average number of consecutive failed payment would just be 1 in this example.
Eventually the table would look like this:

```
cus_id |tran_id.|f_or_s |tran_date  |avg_consec_fail|avg_consec_success
  1    |1       |success|2021-01-01 |1              |1.5
  1    |2       |success|2021-01-15 |1              |1.5
  1    |3       |failed |2021-01-30 |1              |1.5
  1    |4       |success|2021-02-15 |1              |1.5
```

How do I make this happen with `R/dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `rle`

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "customer_id transaction_id. failed_or_success   transaction_date 
  1         1              success            2021-01-01
  1         2              success            2021-01-15
  1         3              failed             2021-01-30
  1         4              success            2021-02-15", header = TRUE)
```

## Code

```
df %>%
  mutate(avg_consec_success = mean(rle(failed_or_success)$length[rle(failed_or_success)$values != "failed"]))

  customer_id transaction_id. failed_or_success transaction_date avg_consec_success
1           1               1           success       2021-01-01                1.5
2           1               2           success       2021-01-15                1.5
3           1               3            failed       2021-01-30                1.5
4           1               4           success       2021-02-15                1.5
```